# When a web application generates excel and image files dynamically

Tags: php, optimization, web-applications

In my web-application I have some forms and based to those forms, users will generate some excel and chart files(.xls and .png). Each use has to generate at least 2 excel files and 5 png files.

The problem is that when is about to generate those files it takes 2 seconds for a excels file and 1 second for a chart. I'm using the [PHPExcel](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel) and [pcharts](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) libs.

How to optimize this task?

Comment: try to identify first where is your bottleneck (slow database, slow php code...)

Comment: can you try to profile your code to be sure what part is the most time consuming ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely time of generation depends on how many records you are working with.
Let's suppose this number is in small range..

**Option 1**

1 second for chart generation is ok. For excel files - no.
Possibly PHPExcel library is the one what you may want to replace with your own functions for faster xls file generation. Check out [here](http://www.appservnetwork.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=8). I have used functions from that article before and they are working like a charm. Sure, if you need to nicely format your data, you are forced to use PHPExcel and can nothing to do with that.

**Option 2**

Cache your files server-side.
For example, once you generated chart/xls you can save it to appropriate place, and when user requests later the same chart/xls you are not needed to rebuild it.

Comment: Many thx Andrejs. I like both of your options. Who can give me some links about this caching procedure?

Comment: I doubt you will find copy-paste solution. You need this implement by yourself as this is something very project-specific.